# Lerp like functionality but units instead of percent?

Tags: javascript, math

When you use lerp it returns a vector3 a certain percentage along a line between too vectors.

Instead of using a percentage I want to use distance.

So instead of saying find 25% of the way from point A to B. I would like to say find a distance of 50 from point A towards point B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the distance to a percentage by dividing it by the distance between A and B. Then plug it into your existing percentage lerping function.